# Simulate alt+tab in Python

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm running in Windows 8.1 this code:

```
import ctypes, time

ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0) #Alt
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0) #Tab

time.sleep(2)

ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 2, 0) #~Tab
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 2, 0) #~Alt
```

I expected this code simulate hold the Alt key, hold the Tab key, wait 2 seconds, release Tab key, then release Alt key, but it's not working. The code can't hold the keys, just pulse (press and release) the key.

I've tried this code before and worked, but not in Windows 8.1. What can I do?

Comment: I'm assuming that `'2` in the last line is only a copy-paste error, correct? Otherwise I can confirm that this works on Windows 7 for what it's worth.

Comment: True. It's a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a slightly tighter alt-tab method.

```
import pyautogui,time

pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
time.sleep(.2)
pyautogui.press('tab')
time.sleep(.2)
pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
```

Repeat
pyautogui.press('tab')
for the number of times you want to move over, and as userNo99 mentioned you'll  want to include some time.sleep(.2)'s to create a delay in between your actions.

edit: I think ArjunSahlot's hotkey suggestion (below) is definitely worth looking at.

Comment: A better way would be to use the `hotkey` function. You can also provide an interval to simulate the `time.sleep()`. `pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "tab", interval=0.2)`. Check out the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-hotkey-function)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but you have to have a delay between alt and tab as well.

```
from time import sleep
import ctypes

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32

user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0) #Alt
sleep(1)
user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0) #Tab
sleep(1)
user32.keybd_event(0x09, 0, 2, 0) #~Tab
sleep(0.1)
user32.keybd_event(0x12, 0, 2, 0) #~Alt
```

Should work.